# App not executing in Xcode after successful build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I have created an iOS app with the Cordova framework (version 2.1.0). I am running it in Xcode (version 4.5.2) in the iOS 6.1 Simulator, but the app doesn't seem to load, even though the build is successful.

What could be the reason for this blank display in simulator?

Comment: Does the app show a blank screen on the simulator, or does it refuse to run at all?

Comment: Check you jQuery/javascript code, you may be having some jQuery or JavaScript error.

Comment: Is there any error message? Could you look up if there is any log message about the simulator run in the OSX Log-Console (Console.app)

Comment: Reset the simulator and again try to run the app

Comment: Are you loading any files? Remember iOS devices are case sensitive with file/folder names. Also remember that the iOS simulator is case insensitive. That means an insensitive file reference will work on simulator but will not work in device.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting blank display in the simulator tells me that your app is being loaded but the view is not setup for some reason. Check the following method in your AppDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Try the following code in the above method to set the main screen to some color (say Red):

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```